# Expand email distribution list

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office365api, outlook-restapi

I need to expand (recursively) email distribution list in Outlook 365. Is it possible to achieve using [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api)?

As far as I understand it can be done using EWS, but I'd like to avoid extra complexity of working with EWS SOAP messages in Javascript code.

Comment: Are you looking for lists created within Outlook or Groups from  AD?

Comment: Both would be the best, but if there is a way to get data for at least one of them I could start with that.

Comment: you can use [`ews-javascript-api`](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api) to consume EWS without manual SOAP transformation.

ExpandDL operation is not supported by outlook-addin btw.